# Reading txt file and making 2d char array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a txt file with the following:

```
%%%%%%%
%Q%&%%%
%%%&&&%
%&%&%%%
%&%&%%%
%&%&&7%
%&%%%&%
%&&&%&%
%%%&&&%
```

This is just an example -- the text file could be any 2d array (varying width and height and characters).

I want to read it in and make a 2d char array in java.

I am trying to use a scanner method that reads the lines as a string and then converts to a charArray:

```
String theString = "";
        File fd = new File("input.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fd);;
        theString = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(fd);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found! Application terminated\n" + e.toString());
            return;
        }

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
               theString = theString + "\n" + sc.nextLine();
        }
        sc.close();
        char[][] charArray= theString.toCharArray();
```

However, the debugger wants me to change to char[] instead of of char[][]

How can I get the desired results?

Comment: The compiler is not wrong. Calling `toCharArray` on a string that has newlines still produces a one-dimensional array.

Comment: Ya, I know.. but that is where I'm at. What is the proper method to read that file in and get the char[][] data struct?

Comment: Either know how many lines are in the file beforehand or split your string on newlines -> convert every element to char[] -> add to char[][]

Answer (score 2):

The `str.toCharArray()` method output a `char[]` of the original string. So the workaround is to add it to the `char[][]` line-by-line instead.

Since you do not know how many lines exactly are there in the `input.txt`, you cannot pre-determine the `char[][]`'s size. One way to do so is to add it to an ArrayList so you know the size of the result array. You can then put it back the `char[][]`.

```
String theString = "";
        File fd = new File("input.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fd);;
        theString = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(fd);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found! Application terminated\n" + e.toString());
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
               lst.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        sc.close();

        char[][] result = new char[lst.size()][lst.get(0).length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
            char[] charArray= lst.get(i).toCharArray();
            result[i] = charArray;
        }
```